# Oracle SQL 'OVER' partition error

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I'm trying to use this code on Oracle and it errors out. The 'partition' statement is highlighted. How do I fix this ?

```
select 
case when b.c_1 = 1 then b.workkey else null end workkey,
b.total_value total_value,
b.namekey namekey
from (select distinct workkey,total_value,namekey, 
      rownum() over (partition by workkey) as c_1 
      from report.arturdup
     ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct function is `row_number()`:

```
select (case when b.c_1 = 1 then b.workkey end) as workkey,
       b.total_value as total_value,
       b.namekey as namekey
from (select distinct workkey, total_value, namekey,
             row_number() over (partition by workkey order by b.workkey) as c_1
      from report.arturdup
     ) b;
```

Note:  You don't need a subquery for this:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by workkey order by workkey) = 1
             then b.workkey
        end) as workkey,
       b.total_value,
       b.namekey
from report.arturdup;
```

Notes:

- In most databases, `order by` is required (in some it is not, but I always use `order by`.
- `else NULL` is redundant.
- You don't need to assign a column alias that is already the name of the column.
- I always use `as` for column aliases.